# Ruby on rails routes using AngularJS doesn't load the first time

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, routes

Alrigth, this is kinda hard to explain, so if you need further information just let me know.

I'm using Ruby on Rails Routing, I know is wrong.. I should use Angular's.

Anyway, everytime I move out to the next view, that view doesn't load properly, is like the controller didn't run at all. If I press refresh(F5) will work perfectly.

Example>>
localhost:3000/dashboard

[image]

No error console btw...

If I refresh>

[image]

Just to clarify, Is not only about how it looks. My $resource is not working either, therefore my page is blank.

I hope anyone could help me!

Comment: Are you using turbolinks gem?

Comment: Yes, could be that?

Comment: I bet, try to remove it.

Comment: see [rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)